# What is [object] in PHP?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm using AJAX to get data from server. The following is the php file.

```
       myphp.php

    $Product_name = $_POST['path'];
        $message['message'] .= '<tr><td>' . ($Product_name) . '</td></tr>';
$message['message'] .= '</table>';
    echo json_encode($message);
        ......
```

When i get response on html page I'm getting '[object]'.

```
$.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "uploader.php",
                   async: false,
                   data: {submit_question:'1', 
                       path: $("[name='path']").val()},


                   success: function(response, status){
                            var ajax_message = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

                            $('#status').html(ajax_message.message);



                   }

                 });
```

Can anybody tell me what does this mean?

Comment: It means you have an object. Show more code, otherwise this is hard to answer precisely.

Comment: What exactly are you executing to see what you're 'getting'? How do you call your ajax?

Comment: Are you using `alert()` inside your ajax success function?

Comment: What is `$Product_name`? Can you show the code where this variable is created so we can diagnose further please?

Comment: $message['message'] .= '<tr><td>' . print_r($Product_name) . '</td></tr>';
 $message['message'] .= '<tr><td>' . $Product_description . '</td></tr>'; 
 
 $message['message'] .= '</table>';
 echo json_encode($message);

Comment: I'm using JQUERY AJAX function to send data to php file

Comment: @fawad: Add this to your question, not in the comments please.

Comment: $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload-controller.php",
        async: false,
        data: {submit_question:'1', 
         questiontext: $("[name='questiontext']").val(), 
 },
         
          
        success: function(response, status){
           var ajax_message = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
           $('#status').html(ajax_message.message);
           
   
 
        }
       
      });

Comment: You're trying to echo <tr><td> in json-parsed object?

Comment: you can show more code of upload.php page?

Comment: That is the complete code. No other line of code is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means that you probably fetched this from database as  an object.

Try this command

```
print_r($Product_name);
```

to see all objected variables

Comment: No, i'm not using any database but let me get the output of print_r

Comment: `var_dump` is usually a bit more descriptive

Comment: [object] is not something php would do, I think php would rather give an error that an object could not be converted to string. The alert() function typically gives [object] when alerting an object.

Comment: @Pelshoff: yes, but in that case $Product name came from javascript/ajax request.

Comment: Yes, it is coming from ajax request

Comment: @fawad: but you can't proccess response if you have html elements in your json-expected-response

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
alert(ajax_message.message.toSource());
```

Placed after the `parseJSON` to see the full response, you can use the `$.each` function to walk over the object revealing your values inside the object.

Comment: yup, that's probably the best solution. +1 :)